# Renaming Plone "Members" id

Tags: plone

Is it possible to rename the id of Plone's "Members" folder?  I want to use the term "Accounts" instead.  I tried doing it via folder_listing and rename.  It works but "My Folder" in the user menu no longer appears.  The conditions set for it now returns false.  I can just rename the Title.  However, the URL would still show ../Members/..

Is it possible to change its id without issues or is this hard coded?  I am expecting that I can just change the value of an attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible. You will need to make changes in the ZMI to the portal_membership tool.
It expects the folder to be called "Members". In the screenshot below I have customized my system to look for a folder called "Persons".

[image: view of the portal_membership tool]

Comment: Thanks. I did not know where to look for the attribute.